# How can a linear autoencoder with $h=1$ hidden unit reconstruct any rank 1 matrix?

Tags: pca, dimensionality-reduction, linear-algebra, autoencoders, matrix-decomposition

I've had this as a homework problem as a true or false type of question and I'm trying to wrap my head around why this is true.

Is the reason simply represent each datapoint as a scaled version of a single vector?

Could someone illustrate this for me I've been having a hard time coming up with an example.

If I am completely off I would also be super grateful for an intuitive explanation.

Many thanks!

Comment: How many principal components would you expect out of a rank 1 matrix?